# Headphones stop working. Restart fixes it but happens again and again

Tags: sound, headphones

On Ubuntu 20.04. Replugging the headphones into the audio jack does not fix. Occasionally it fixes on it's own but usually need to restart. Have tried force restarting things like also but to no avail.

Regular sound works. I.e. sound suddently starts coming out of main speakers.

I see this in dmesg, not sure:

[670221.101750] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 10
[670221.281230] rfkill: input handler disabled
[670235.396911] rfkill: input handler enabled
[670235.853945] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 33
[670236.345942] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 35
[670237.597075] rfkill: input handler disabled
[670243.262896] UpdateHalRAMask8812A => mac_id:0, networkType:0x0b, mask:0xffffffff
                     ==> rssi_level:2, rate_bitmap:0x0fffffff
[670246.774441] show_signal_msg: 18 callbacks suppressed
[670246.774443] SGI_video_sync[1267823]: segfault at e6 ip 000055c3b076120d sp 00007ff0e054d680 error 6 in Discord[55c3ad2c0000+53ad000]

And anecdotally, after quitting *firefox* this time the microphones reappeared and started working again.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally have issues with a USB headset and restarting Pulse audio often does the trick.

```
pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start
```

I'm not convinced your scenario is the same but it's worth a shot. The other option might be to install pavucontrol, which allows you to change the audio settings per application. Might be usfeul if Firefox is somehow hogging devices.